# Automatically register users

Tags: asp.net-core, testing, web, automation

I have created my first kind of complex application.
Now I need to register around 200 accounts to the application for testing the performance. Is there some sort of tool/bot that can do this through the web or perhaps some solution to insert them directly in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use FakeData library for that. If you search Nuget for this package u can easily find. Just run code like this when u want to insert users.

```
         for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
               
                string name = FakeData.NameData.GetFirstName();
                string lastname = FakeData.NameData.GetSurname();
                string email = FakeData.NetworkData.GetEmail();
                string password = "Password!123";
                //if you need you can get more data 
                Person p = new Person { Email = email, Name = name, Lastname = lastname ,Password=password};

                //here is your registiration code 
                RegisterModelUser(p);
            }
```